# add_submenu_page to post_type post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add a settings submenu page to the post_type post, but I can not get it to work. The page exists if I go to the url directly, but it does not appear in the sidebar menu. If I change the post type to page, it works perfectly fine, but the settings I'm trying to add apply specifically to the post post_type.

is there a solution for this?

Thanks,

```
function the_post_settings() {
  add_submenu_page(
    'edit.php?post_type=post',
    'Post Settings',
    'Settings',
    'edit_posts',
    'post-settings',
    'post_settings'
  );
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'the_post_settings');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I had to change edit.php?post_type=post to just edit.php.

All is well now. Hope I helped someone else in the future